# exclude names without a comma

Tags: grep

How do I exclude names from my list that have no comma and output them to a file? Should I use grep?

Example:

```
Charlie Chapman
William, Henry
Gary, Stevens
Mark Twain
Harry Potter
Smithy, John
Mon
```

Answer (score 5):

You have several options.

With `grep`:

```
grep -v , file > new_file
```

With GNU `sed` or BSD `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/,/d' file
```

With `gawk` version 4.1.0 and above:

```
gawk -i inplace -v INPLACE_SUFFIX=.bak '!/,/' file
```

With `perl`:

```
perl -i.bak -nle 'print unless /,/' file
```